# JavaScript IF condition has unexpected result

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner trying to make a quick text-based thing with what I learned in one day of Javascript. Why can't this code get past the first IF condition? If I type anything other than "yes" it still says "woohoo!" I've tried else if statements and everything but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.

```
var firstName = prompt("What's your first name?");
var lastName = prompt("Ooo I like that. So, what's your last name?");

var answer = prompt(firstName + " " + lastName + ", huh? Wow, I love that name! I'm a little bored right now...so, would you like to play a Choose Your Own Adventure Game?");

if (answer === "yes" || "Yes") {
    alert("Woohoo! I haven't played this in a long time. Okay, here goes. Press the OK button to start.");
} 
else {
    alert("Oh, okay. Well, I'll see you later.");
}
```

Comment: Remove the || "Yes" part first and test your code again. Also learn how to use F12 tools in a browser to debug JavaScript code.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Removing that part was the first thing I should've done no doubt. I didn't know about the F12 thing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `(answer === "yes" || "Yes")` condition... `"Yes"` always evaluates to `true` (in Javascript), so you're basically saying 'does answer === "yes" or true'... which is always true. To correct the logic, you should use `(answer === "yes" || answer === "Yes")`

I'd normalise the output (and check for a response), so that you can just check for one condition...

```js
var firstName = prompt("What's your first name?");
var lastName = prompt("Ooo I like that. So, what's your last name?");

var answer = prompt(firstName + " " + lastName + ", huh? Wow, I love that name! I'm a little bored right now...so, would you like to play a Choose Your Own Adventure Game?");

if (answer && answer.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
    alert("Woohoo! I haven't played this in a long time. Okay, here goes. Press the OK button to start.");
} 
else {
    alert("Oh, okay. Well, I'll see you later.");
}
```

Comment: As soon as I saw your answer, I understood. Thanks for the clarification. I haven't learned anything about the .toLowerCase stuff yet. I have a long, long way to go. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Prog No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Non-empty strings (such as the string 'Yes') are always truthy, so `if (answer === "yes" || "Yes") {` will always evaluate to `if (true)`. If you want to check to see if the answer is either `yes` or `Yes`, you can put them into an array and use `.includes`:

```js
const yesArr = ['yes', 'Yes'];
console.log(yesArr.includes('Yes'));
console.log(yesArr.includes('No'));
```

Or if the capitalization doesn't matter at all, either convert the string to lower case first and then check:

```js
console.log('YES'.toLowerCase() === 'yes')
```

Or you might use a case-insensitive regular expression:

```js
console.log(/yes/i.test('YES'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't even learned about arrays yet so all that flew over my head. I'm writing all my code right now in the JS console in Chrome just to give you an idea of how noob I am.

Answer (score 0):

Just correct your if condition,it should be

```
if (answer || answer.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
//dosomething
}
```

It will check the answer for both the values ("yes" and "Yes").